# ASP.NET MVC - Switching from SQL Server Express to Compact Edition - Connection Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, connection-string, appharbor

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project - **CodeFirst with Entity Framework** - that was connected to a SQL Server Express database generated by EF and it was working just fine.

However, I am trying to deploy to AppHarbor and having some issues with the version of SQL running there connecting with my app.

So, I noticed that they have an example project that is utilizing SQL Server Compact Edition 4.  Here is the web.config file for that project:  https://github.com/friism/CodeFirstMigrations/blob/master/Web/Web.config

Also, I found a tutorial about how to include a SQL Server CE database in your project on Microsoft's ASP.NET site:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

I decided to create a `FranchiseManagerData.sdf` file in my **App_Data** folder and modify my connection string and app settings to match theirs.  Here's what my Web.config looks like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FranchiseManagerEntities"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|FranchiseManagerData.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I run my application, I get a DataException error that says:  `The underlying provider failed on Open.`

It looks like what is happening is that the application is still looking for the old database that was generated by Entity Framework that had the name:  `FranchiseManagerTest.Models.FranchiseManagerContext` - EF was naming it after my data context class.

Here is the error that is displayed after stopping debugging:

```
 Cannot open database "FranchiseManagerTest.Models.FranchiseManagerContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'COMPANY\UserName'.
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.  Also, I've deleted the contents of the bin folder and did a clean rebuild again, however, it still seems to be looking for the old database connection.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get my project to look for the local SQL Server CE database I made and not the previous database?

If I need to supply any further details please let me know.

**Thanks in advance.**

---

### EDIT

Here is a portion of the System.Web section of my Web.config file:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication?

Comment: Hi Erik - I updated my OP to show the authentication mode.  Yes, it's using the default forms authentication with the Account controller login method.

Comment: ... although, none of the authorization has been set up in the controllers yet - it's just that one line in Web.config so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FormsAuthentication doesn't by default have the ability to use Sql CE (to my knowledge).
 I have used [EJ's SQL Server Compact 4.0 ASP.NET Membership provider](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-40-aspnet-membership.html)  without any issues.

Also, it sounds like you'll have to update your Entity Framework connection to use the SQL Server CE database correctly.

**Update**

As of .Net 4.5, the new SimpleMemembership Providers and Univerasl Providers naively support Sql CE.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know about the incompatibility between the two.